# Lighthouse returned error: generic::internal: APP::1: Abnormal renderer termination, status = crashed

Tags: lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I'm getting this error: Lighthouse returned error: generic::internal: APP::1: Abnormal renderer termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1

For one of the websites I work on https://www.tronitechnik.de
I'm tested it with: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tronitechnik.de%2F&tab=desktop

Any ideas what could be causing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I get the same for my homepage.
The smallest portion of code I could extract that causes the crash is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<body>
This is a test&shy;test&shy;test&shy;test&shy;test. Die testtesten Typen wurden vom TÜV SÜD mit dem Siegel <a href="#">„Ge&shy;prüfte Si&shy;cherheit“ (GS)</a>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems to be the combination of some parts (I could not figure out which exactly) that seem to cause the crash. If I delete e.g. EITHER the text between  or the text before it, the crash does not happen.

As a workaround I therefore temporarily removed all soft hyphens (&shy) from the HTML output until this is fixed, because I fear the Lighthouse crash might affect my ranking at Google.

Comment: Thank you, it was wirklick an &shy; of which we had it 6 times in the source text!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was one single css-line. I tested it like this: Deactivated my css sheet. The test worked fine. Then I just deactivated parts of my css to find the problem. On my page the trouble was caused by setting inline style to h1. Here is the site. For design reasons I kept it: https://www.pixelfutter.de

Page speed does not work. When I set my post h1 to inline. The test works. This is a bug obviously.